# What's the best (Pythonic) way to remove certain duplicate elements from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following example:

```
In [1]: lst = list(range(10)) * 2

In [2]: lst
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [3]: for i, x in enumerate(list(lst)):
   ...:     if i > 10 and x % 2:
   ...:         lst.remove(x)
   ...:         

In [4]: lst
Out[4]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So this strategy doesn't work, as it removes the first occurrence of item in the `list`, which is not what I want.

```
In [5]: lst = list(range(10)) * 2

In [6]: for i, x in enumerate(list(lst)):
   ...:     if i > 10 and x % 2:
   ...:         del lst[i]
   ...:         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bbec803a1844> in <module>()
      1 for i, x in enumerate(list(lst)):
      2     if i > 10 and x % 2:
----> 3         del lst[i]
      4 

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

My other strategy doesn't work either, because the copy of the initial `list` eventually has larger index, as the original `list` has items constantly removed from it.

The following does work:

```
In [7]: lst = list(range(10)) * 2

In [8]: idx = 0

In [9]: for i, x in enumerate(list(lst)):
   ...:     if i > 10 and x % 2:
   ...:         lst.pop(i-idx)
   ...:         idx += 1
   ...:         

In [10]: lst
Out[10]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

And also this one:

```
In [11]: lst = list(range(10)) * 2

In [12]: idx = 0

In [13]: for i, li in enumerate(x for x in lst.copy()):
    ...:     if i > 10 and li % 2:
    ...:         lst.pop(i-idx)
    ...:         idx += 1
    ...:         

In [14]: lst
Out[14]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Is any of the working methods better than the other? Is there a better way to achieve what I want? What if I have `or` statement in the `if` test?

```
In [15]: lst = list(range(10)) * 2

In [16]: idx = 0

In [17]: for i, x in enumerate(list(lst)):
    ...:     if i > 10 and (x % 2 or x // 5):
    ...:         lst.pop(i-idx)
    ...:         idx += 1
    ...:

In [18]: lst
Out[18]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself writing a `for` loop to construct or modify a list, ask yourself how you might do it with a list comprehension instead. List comprehensions are Pythonic.

```
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i <= 10 or x % 2 == 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution above would be my first choice using *list comprehension* but for an alternate solution, even if just to learn a new tool, we could use `filterfalse`

```
from itertools import filterfalse

l = [*range(10)]*2
l = list(filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] > 10 and x[1] % 2, enumerate(l)))
print([y for x, y in l])
```

> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
> ```